# Getting User ID or Name from Google Plus Profile Url

Tags: php, regex, google-plus

GooglePlus profile urls can be written as:

```
https://plus.google.com/117302453758282711096/
https://plus.google.com/u/0/105604861727423445668
https://plus.google.com/u/1/105604861727423445668
https://plus.google.com/+tuando
```

In php or even regular expressions in general to help others, how can I parse this url to return the username/userid?

Comment: Have you tried something to get the userid out of the url? Also with userid you mean only the last part of the url: `105604861727423445668` or also this: `1/105604861727423445668`?

Comment: 1/ isn't apart of the user id

Comment: So you just want the last part of the url?

Answer (score 0):

'*username/userid*' in such case is the last section in url.
 Use `parse_url` function to get the last section from url path:

```
$url1 = "https://plus.google.com/u/1/105604861727423445668/";
$url2 = "https://plus.google.com/+tuando";

$path = parse_url(trim($url1,"/"), PHP_URL_PATH);

echo "<pre>";

$last_section = end(explode("/", $path));

var_dump($last_section);   // string(21) "105604861727423445668"
```

...

```
// checking $url2

$path = parse_url(trim($url2,"/"), PHP_URL_PATH);

echo "<pre>";

$last_section = end(explode("/", $path));

var_dump($last_section);   // string(7) "+tuando"
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 0):

Possible Regex: `plus.google.com/((\+\w+)|((|u\/(1|0)\/)\d{21}))`

Would match username in $2 or id in $4

Assumed the id is a string of 21 numbers ...